# OpenCart: Add to Wishlist With Product Size and Color

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

In my website. If i add a product to wishlist after selecting a size. The product is getting added to the wishlist but the size is not getting saved along with it. Is it possible to save a product size and color while adding a product to wish list in opencart?

Heres the beta link : http://beta.camelkart.in/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=115

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible by default, but there may be an extension that does it, I suggest you search the marketplace: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension